# Как получить id элемента из popup?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Хочу получить капчу, чтобы отправить его на распознавание. В хроме я его могу найти, но почему то selenium говорит что элемент не найден

```
var reCaptha = driver.FindElementById("rc-imageselect");
```

Урл с капчей
https://www.avito.ru/rossiya#login?s=h

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это invisible recapthca, она активируется не всегда. Это значит что поиск каптчи нужно делать после нажатия кнопочки отправки всей формы.